# while clicking the buttton i am not getting the output

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I know how to write this in pure javascript, but I am new to angular.. when clicking the submit I am not getting any result..

index.html

```
<input type="text"   ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">
      <input type="password"   ng-model="password" placeholder="Password">
      <ion-button expand="block" name="submit" (click)="login()">Login</ion-button>
```

index.ts

```
    export class LoginPage implements OnInit {
      username;
      password;

      login() {
        if(this.username == "admin" && this.password == "admin") {
          alert("helow")
        }
      }
```

Comment: try chrome dev tools and put a breakpoint in the start of login function and check if it reaches there

Comment: Are u using angularjs or angular2+?

Comment: Take a look at this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-4-angular-8-start-template-wt4rdz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change ng-model with [(ngModel)]

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password" placeholder="Password">
<ion-button expand="block" name="submit" (click)="login()">Login</ion-button>
```